# difficulty using enter key as tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm creating forms and needed to use "enter key press as tab key" to focus next text fields and after completion of the form, button should be pressed.

my code works except for the button press part, it does nothing to the button.

thanks in advance...

```js
$(window).load(function(){
      document.getElementById("Editbox1").focus();
function tab(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        e.target.nextSibling.nextSibling.focus();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++)
{
    var input = inputs[x];
    input.onkeypress = tab;
}


    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wb_Form1" style="position:absolute;background-color:#F7F9FC;left:307px;top:153px;width:377px;height:256px;z-index:5">
<form name="Form1" method="post" action="#" enctype="text/plain" id="Form1">
<input type="text" id="Editbox1" style="position:absolute;left:195px;top:65px;width:170px;height:18px;border:1px #C0C0C0 solid;font-family:Courier New;font-size:13px;z-index:0" name="Editbox1" value="">
<input type="text" id="Editbox2" style="position:absolute;left:196px;top:98px;width:171px;height:18px;border:1px #C0C0C0 solid;font-family:Courier New;font-size:13px;z-index:1" name="Editbox2" value="">
<input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left:198px;top:134px;width:96px;height:25px;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;z-index:2">
<img src="images/img0001.gif" id="Text1" alt="" border="0" style="position:absolute;left:65px;top:72px;width:113px;height:16px;z-index:3">
<img src="images/img0002.gif" id="Text2" alt="" border="0" style="position:absolute;left:65px;top:102px;width:113px;height:16px;z-index:4">
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Curious as to what the use case or need is to subvert normal keyboard interaction  in your forms?

Comment: To make flow of the data entering easy

Comment: Don't you think that calling `preventDefault` on input type submit will prevent its default behavior, which is submitting form?

Comment: if i removed the following button is functioning as intended   <img src="images/img0001.gif" id="Text1" alt="" border="0" style="position:absolute;left:65px;top:72px;width:113px;height:16px;z-index:3">
<img src="images/img0002.gif" id="Text2" alt="" border="0" style="position:absolute;left:65px;top:102px;width:113px;height:16px;z-index:4">

Comment: So, on button focus enter it should be submitted?

Comment: yes that's what i want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to differentiate the button click by its id, you have two approaches

1st you can bind the enter function by using the length of the inputs, get last id and differentiate it.

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  document.getElementById("Editbox1").focus();

  function tab(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      console.log('test');
      e.target.nextSibling.nextSibling.focus();
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
  function submitForm(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {     
      document.getElementByName("Form1").submit();
    }
  }
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {
    var input = inputs[x];   
    if (x === (inputs.length - 1)) {    
      input.onkeypress = submitForm;
    } else {
      input.onkeypress = tab;
    }
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wb_Form1" style="position:absolute;background-color:#F7F9FC;left:307px;top:153px;width:377px;height:256px;z-index:5">
  <form name="Form1" method="post" action="#" enctype="text/plain" id="Form1">
    <input type="text" id="Editbox1" style="position:absolute;left:195px;top:65px;width:170px;height:18px;border:1px #C0C0C0 solid;font-family:Courier New;font-size:13px;z-index:0" name="Editbox1" value="">
    <input type="text" id="Editbox2" style="position:absolute;left:196px;top:98px;width:171px;height:18px;border:1px #C0C0C0 solid;font-family:Courier New;font-size:13px;z-index:1" name="Editbox2" value="">
    <input type="text" id="Editbox3" style="position:absolute;width:171px;height:18px;border:1px #C0C0C0 solid;font-family:Courier New;font-size:13px;z-index:1" name="Editbox2" value="">
    <input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left:198px;top:134px;width:96px;height:25px;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;z-index:2">
    <img src="images/img0001.gif" id="Text1" alt="" border="0" style="position:absolute;left:65px;top:72px;width:113px;height:16px;z-index:3">
    <img src="images/img0002.gif" id="Text2" alt="" border="0" style="position:absolute;left:65px;top:102px;width:113px;height:16px;z-index:4">
  </form>
</div>
```

2nd one you can differentiate it using button id when enter is pressed.

```
 if (e.which == 13 && e.target.id !== "Button1") {
```

```js
$(window).load(function() {
  document.getElementById("Editbox1").focus();

  function tab(e) {
    if (e.which == 13 && e.target.id !== "Button1") {
      console.log('test');
      e.target.nextSibling.nextSibling.focus();
      e.preventDefault();
    }else{
      alert('submit')
    }
  }

  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
  for (var x = 0; x < inputs.length; x++) {
    var input = inputs[x];
    input.onkeypress = tab;
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wb_Form1" style="position:absolute;background-color:#F7F9FC;left:307px;top:153px;width:377px;height:256px;z-index:5">
  <form name="Form1" method="post" action="#" enctype="text/plain" id="Form1">
    <input type="text" id="Editbox1" style="position:absolute;left:195px;top:65px;width:170px;height:18px;border:1px #C0C0C0 solid;font-family:Courier New;font-size:13px;z-index:0" name="Editbox1" value="">
    <input type="text" id="Editbox2" style="position:absolute;left:196px;top:98px;width:171px;height:18px;border:1px #C0C0C0 solid;font-family:Courier New;font-size:13px;z-index:1" name="Editbox2" value="">
    <input type="text" id="Editbox3" style="position:absolute;width:171px;height:18px;border:1px #C0C0C0 solid;font-family:Courier New;font-size:13px;z-index:1" name="Editbox2" value="">
    <input type="submit" id="Button1" name="" value="Submit" style="position:absolute;left:198px;top:134px;width:96px;height:25px;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;z-index:2">
    <img src="images/img0001.gif" id="Text1" alt="" border="0" style="position:absolute;left:65px;top:72px;width:113px;height:16px;z-index:3">
    <img src="images/img0002.gif" id="Text2" alt="" border="0" style="position:absolute;left:65px;top:102px;width:113px;height:16px;z-index:4">
  </form>
</div>
```